# couldn't find samples in android-sdk directory

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

When I go to the directory `C:/programfiles/android/android-sdk/platform/<version>/`
I couldn't find the samples directory.
I installed all the versions of the `sdk` with samples from the sdk manager opening from eclipse but I couldn't install the same when I open it from
`start--> all programs--> android--> sdk`
when I open sdk from eclipse it shows installed which when opened from start menu shows as not installed.

Can anyone help me to find the samples directory?
I create the project from samples in eclipse.

Comment: Inside the `platforms` directory you will have many platform versions sub directory. Inside that sub directory(for eg. `android-14`), if you have downloaded the sample, you will find the `Samples` directory.

Comment: i checked that directory but couldn't find the samples directory

i could open the samples from eclipse only but couldn't find the samples form windows explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a system wide search for the file "ApiDemos.java" which is part of the API Demos sample.

If that is not found, then there are few sensible possibilities:

- The samples are not actually installed
- The samples are installed under the ownership of a different user/administrator, such that you cannot access them but the eclipse plugin somehow can
- The file system is corrupt

Comment: "The samples are installed under the ownership of a different user/administrator, such that you cannot access them but the eclipse plugin somehow can" this solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

`C:/Program Files (x86)/android/android-sdk/samples/` ?

Just to make sure which SDK directory your eclipse is using, open in eclipse:

Window -> Preferences -> Android and open the path under "SDK Location". If you installed them they should be there.

Comment: no samples directory in android-sdk

Comment: Just to make sure which SDK directory your eclipse is using, open in eclipse:

Window -> Preferences -> Android and open the path under "SDK Location". The samples should be there.

Comment: the sdk location in Window->Preferences-> android and in the path C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk everything looks fine but the samples directory is missing

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 (and most likely in Windows XP and Windows Vista) the standard paths are:

**32-bit**

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\samples
```

**64-bit**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples
```

Comment: he says that he already went to the directory C:/programfiles/android/android-sdk ... so it should not be a problem of 32 / 64 bit...

Comment: i use windows 7.
there is no samples directory in C:\program files\Android\android-sdk\

Comment: When you reopen the SDK Manager, does it say that the Samples are installed?

Comment: yeah it show as samples are installed when opened from eclipse but shows as not installed when opened from start menu

Comment: wht about ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the Samples you may find it at the following place:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\<android-version>\samples/
```

Check this detail link:
http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

If its not present then using `SDK Manager` you can download the required platform version samples.

**EDIT**

If none of the solutions are working make a windows search for the folder `samples`. You will surely find it.

Comment: i have downloaded the samples but i couldn't find the samples directory.

Comment: i could create project in eclipse from the samples.
but i couldn't find the samples directory in the sdk directory.
but i need to access the samples directory(not through eclipse)

Comment: searching in windows also couldn't give me the soultion. thanks for your reply. i think i have to reinstall if i need to view samples directory from explorer

Answer (score 0):

Try `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\samples\<android-version>`

Answer (score -1):

You can currently view them online at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/05523fb0b48280a5364908b00768ec71edb847a2/samples